# Make javascript prompt text read only

Tags: javascript, html, prompt, readonly

I have a prompt containing a url, however I would like to ensure that this text cannot be manipulated (changed, scripts injected, etc.). Would making this text "readonly" solve this problem? I'll post my code below, thank you!

```
Html
<div id="button">

Js
<script>
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
        prompt('Copy and share this link!', 'www.webapp.com');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: It is not possible with a prompt.

Comment: Do you need to use `prompt` or can it be a custom popup?

Comment: Tomasz Kasperczyk It could be a custom popup or modal, though I thought that a prompt would be most efficient..unless it isn't : )

Comment: How about using `alert()`?

Comment: Anything that runs in the browser can be manipulated by the client.

Comment: @Alex How would that prevent modification of what gets displayed in the alert?

Comment: @Barmar maybe I misunderstood, I thought the OP was trying to prevent the prompt text from being edited client-side

Comment: @Alex He said he wants to prevent injected scripts from modifying it.

Comment: There's pretty much nothing that an injected script can't do to change how the main script behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a solution for that, as JS prompts are not designed for this use case.

In case there is no direct solution, maybe you can try a more "traditional" approach, using a copy library, such as [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) -- which might be a friendlier solution for your users, too.

Comment: Cristian Dinu I saw clipboard.js this morning! I was hoping for a very minimal solution, however this looks promising. Thank you!

Comment: Another trick I used was to display the text in a disabled input. But that needs a custom dialog, too.

Comment: How does any of this solve the problem? An injected script can change what gets put into the call to `Clipboard.js` functions, or what you put into the disabled input.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, well, would you happen to have recommendations as to how I might come as close to possible to avoiding any script infections in this particular case? Just curious.. thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can. If someone installs a browser extension, it can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @barmar Okay.. Thank you for your comments. Much appreciated : )

Answer (score 0):

Prompt is used when you need user input against something. For the simple display of information, you can use `alert()`, it will make the text uneditable.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm trying a feature using alert instead, too.